Words with non-gikun/non-jukujikun kanji spellings for which it is not clear which kanji certain kana belong to
Are there words with kanji spellings for which it is not clear which kanji certain kana belong to?
Note that I'm explicitly excluding gikun/jukujinkun from my question, such as the well-known example 今日 (きょう).
A purely hypothetical example would be a word あかさ/akasa with the kanji spelling XY where

X has at least the readings あ/a and あか/aka and
Y has at least the readings かさ/kasa and さ/sa.


There is this surname 小宮山(こみやま). You can't tell whether や belongs to 宮 or 山. Not sure if こみややま got shortened at some point or those kanji were assigned to こみやま from the beginning.
